# Can't connect to local MySQL server -

Tags: apache2, mysql

```
sudo mysql
```

is responding with

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Any idea why? Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: The service may not be running. Try `systemctl start mysql.service `

Comment: @guillermochamorro: Interesting. It works now without doing anything. Only rebooting the computer. Yesterday reboot was not helping.

Comment: You can always check the status of the service with `systemctl status mysql.service`